# Appending to a URL using PHP before the page loads

Tags: php, html, url

I'm trying to figure out how to append a random query string to the end of a URL the first time someone visits my page. For example, say someone navigates to my site at, www.example.com. If everything goes according to plan, they'll hit my index.php file, the URL in the address bar will be www.example.com, and everything will be hunky dory.

However, what I would like is for when that person types www.example.com into their address bar and hits go, they are directed to my index.php file, but the URL is changed to:

www.example.com/?fromdatabase=randomthing

I have the database all setup and I can get random values from it no problem, the problem is changing the URL so that the random values are appended before the page loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the beginning of your index.php

```
<?php 
if(empty($_GET['fromdatabase']))
{ 
die(header('Location: http://www.example.com/?fromdatabase=randomthing'));
} 
?>
```

Greetings,
Fredyy

Comment: Awesome it worked! Now how might break out of: 'Location:
http://www.example.com/?fromdatabase=randomthing' 
and tack on a variable like so:

'Location: http://www.example.com/?fromdatabase='+$row[0]

Comment: `header('Location: example.com/?fromdatabase='.$row[0]);`

Comment: You are the real hero here, Hailwood. ty

Answer (score 2):

You could just redirect the user, if there is no querystring.

For example:

```
if(!isset($_GET['fromdatabase']))
{
   header('location: index.php?fromdatabase=randomthing');
   exit;
}
```

However, it doesnt make much sense. Why do you want to redirect the user to a different url, you could just display the content in your index.

Comment: But note that this will only work if you have outputted __nothing__ to the browser, or if output buffering (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) is set sufficiently.

Comment: I'm trying to get the new facebook open graph to work. I have a single php page (index.php) that offers a random link to a drink recipe every time you reload the page. If a user clicks on the link and has given permission, it posts that drink to their timeline. The problem is, because the URL is the same every time (index.php), the first time that any drink is posted to facebook, facebook caches whatever the open graph info was for that drink and whenever anyone else clicks and submits a different drink to their timeline, facebook uses the chached info instead of the new open graph info.

Comment: If I add a different query string onto the end of the url every time, to facebook, it looks like I have 100 different pages, and thus 100 different open graph objects, when in reality, I have just one page, with 100 different objects.